# could not import android classes

Tags: java, android, eclipse

I have imported an existing android project into eclipse, the src code shows some errors saying

> "The type java.lang.Class cannot be resolved. It is indirectly
>   referenced from required `.class` files" and "the import android
>   cannot be resolved"

Answer (score 0):

Have you downloaded the Android sdk & used it to download the specific target-sdk that your project is built for? If you haven't then you should do this first.

After that you need to tell eclipse where your android-sdk is present. This document explains everything.

http://developer.android.com/sdk/installing.html