# problems with importing android project

Tags: java, android

i have  imported an existing android project into eclipse, it says
**The project was not built since its build path is incomplete. Cannot find the class file for java.lang.Object. Fix the build path then try building this project  tet     Unknown Java Problem**

Comment: exact duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7069205/could-not-import-android-classes

Answer (score 2):

In Eclipse, do the following after selecting your project

1. `Project` -> `Properties` -> `Resource` -> `Android`
2. Check the appropriate target Name (ie Android 2.3.3)
3. Apply

Answer (score 1):

Add the JDK libraries to the build path in the project properties.

Answer (score 0):

Right click your project, and in the "Android" section, make sure you have a version checked.